# Do i have to remove from Index if i delete using Cypher?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

Given i have node or, relation that is added to graph Indexes. When i delete the node / relation, do I also have to remove from Index? We delete within transactions from java API as well us using cypher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using auto indexing then Neo4j will take care of removing it from the index. If you are using manual(or Explicit) indexing then I know there is a cypher way to delete the entire index but not sure if Neo4j supports removing individual entries from the manual index. You can check summarization on different Neo4j indexes [here](http://2scompliment.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/indexing-in-neo4j/).

[Docs on index manipulation with cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-schema-index.html).

Comment: Thanks ! can you please point me to the cypher way of deleting all ? i am fairly new to Neo4j

Comment: @matroyd Updated my post with the link. Accept this as the answer if it helped you.